# Why it does not pass my data trough this Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass a String to another activity using Intents, but i don't know why it doesn't work.

I have two buttons, the first button will add the string(which is a number) from the EditText, then when it is added to the Intent, the user will press the Finish Button to go to the next activity which it will have the String that the  user just wrote in the EditText field,  i have been doing tests to pass the data with an intent and display this "String" in the other activity..but it won't do anything.

This is the Main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Visor.class);
    if (v == addToList) {
        intent.putExtra("number", tasksNumber.getText());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Items Added to List!", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (v == finish ){
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
    }
}
```

This is the activity where it should display the "number":

```
    activityNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_activities);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String theNumber  = intent.getStringExtra("number");

    activityNumber.setText(theNumber);
```

Also i want to check if the user added something to the string(list) before pressing finish but i will be later, first i want to pass the data and display it.

Buttons and EditText from main:

```
    addToList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addtolist);
    activityNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number_activities);
    finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.finish);

    activityNumber.setOnClickListener(this);
    addToList.setOnClickListener(this);
    finish.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Move `intent.putExtra("number", tasksNumber.getText());` line just before `startActivity(intent);` problem is occurring because not setting any value with intent when `if (v == finish )` condition is `true`

Comment: thanks!! but still not working, passing:


            intent.putExtra("number", tasksNumber.getText());
            startActivity(intent);

receiving:


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String theNumber  = intent.getStringExtra("number");
        activityNumber.setText(theNumber);
and still getting errors, it is not displaying the data

Comment: I think my video is helpful for you, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgGYceu0kZ4

Comment: ok, very thanks! the WHOLE problem was because i didn't added the .tostring() when i'm getting the data from the EditText in my ActivityMain java file!.